# Argumentos invalido en Flask Python

Tags: python, django, flask

Quiero crear un json, que se refresque automaticamente, para que el navegador tenga que leerlo cada vez que se abre el template

Hice lo siguiente

```
  parametroderefresco=time.strftime("%S") 
  parametroderefresco=str(parametroderefresco)
  print(parametroderefresco)
  with open("static/data.json?nocache="+parametroderefresco+"", 'w') as file:
      json.dump(data, file)
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'static/data.json?nocache=40'

¿Cual seria la solucion?

Comment: ¿Windows por casualidad?

Comment: Si Windows 10 ,

Comment: Intentas cear un archivo en el directorio `/static` con el nombre  `data.json?nocache=40`... El error se debe a  que ? no es un carácter válido para un nombre de un archivo en Windows, no habría problema en *nix en cambio (aunque dependiendo de la shell puede que se tenga que escapar)

Comment: Justamente tengo un servidor dónde está alojada la web , que es un Ubuntu, por lo tanto voy a probarlo allí, muchísimas gracias